# How to trigger jQuery script on site by Java parser

Tags: javascript, java, parsing, jsoup, htmlunit

I'm trying to parse a vacancies from https://www.epam.com/careers/job-listings?query=java&department=all&city=Kyiv&country=Ukraine
But I dont get anything execept plain text like "Job Listings Global/English Deutschland/Deutsch Россия/Русский"
The problem is when you load a page - browser runs a script that load some vacancies, but how can I undesrstand JSOUP cant "simulate" browser and run a script. I tried HtmlUnit, but it also done nothing.
Question: What should i do? Am I doing something wrong with HtmlUnit?

Jsoup

```
Element page = = Jsoup.connect("https://www.epam.com/careers/job-listings?sort=best_match&query=java&department=all&city=all&country=Poland").get();
```

HtmlUnit

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)) {
    page = webClient.getPage("https://www.epam.com/careers/job-listings?query=java&department=all&city=Kyiv&country=Ukraine");
}
```

I think i need manualy run some script with

```
result = page.executeJavaScript("function aa()");
```

But which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wait a little as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork).

You can use:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    String url = "https://www.epam.com/careers/job-listings?query=java&department=all&city=Kyiv&country=Ukraine";

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    Thread.sleep(3_000);
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
}
```